# New Firebase events are being logged but when uploading it says no data

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Here is the debug log that speak for itself

```
2016-06-24 00:50:34.965 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Event logged. Event name, event params: select_content, {
        "_o" = app;
        "content_type" = "Share_Screen";
        "item_id" = 4;
    }
2016-06-24 00:50:40.969 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Event logged. Event name, event params: select_content, {
        "_o" = app;
        "content_type" = "About_Screen";
        "item_id" = 5;
    }
```

I have truncated bunch of other events for sake of brevity.

```
2016-06-24 00:50:46.346 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Do not schedule an upload task. Task already exists
2016-06-24 00:50:46.394 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled
2016-06-24 00:50:46.394 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Canceling active timer
2016-06-24 00:50:46.395 testApp[13184:] <FIRAnalytics/DEBUG> Cancelling background upload task.
```

Does anyone have clue what is happening here. I have waiting whole day to these events to show up in firebase analytics.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue, and there are two possible solutions I have tried out that work in my case.

1. In GoogleService-Info.plist, enable flag "IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED"
2. When tested on simulator or device, we need to minimize the app into background (so it will send data to firebase server) before hitting the stop debugging button.

Answer (score 3):

1. search in your project for **GoogleService** and find **GoogleService-Info.plist**
2. check IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED , it is boolean, and if it is **NO**, click on **NO** and select **YES**
3. save and run the project, problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't overreact to those messages. No errors are indicated there.  Could it just be that you didn't include "Today" in your date range when you went to view your reports?  Keep in mind that the default date range ("Last 30 Days") does not include Today.  So if you want to see Today's data, change the date range to either "Today" or "Custom" and include Today in the date range.

Comment: I am trying last two days so I guess it should show up. But I took your suggestion and did use custom date selector. Still no luck. :(
That's what that it does not show error is throwing me off. It seem I did every right and there is no error and still its not updating :'(
what is suspicious here is "Events are being logged but it says no data to upload. So might be no data is being sent. That's why nothing is being shown

Answer (score 0):

> No data to upload. Upload task will not be scheduled

The log does say that there is no data to upload so there will be no data to see in the website. Can you please provide a full log or anything that have prefix ?

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex. Yes I do notice that too. But you might have missed the segment above two events are logged. It should be some data. That's I have posted here if same thing is happening to someone else too.

Comment: Yes, events can be logged but at some points between logging and sending data, some how data got lost. I am suspecting database failures so that's why I am asking if you see any other messages related to FIRAnalytics. Can you check the device's log to see if there is anything wrong such as write permission?